# How to save key of each item in the firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using firebase in my react native project.I am saving items and then getting those items in my app. But now I want to edit and delete items based on the key generated by the firebase for each item you can see in the ss.
When I get the data from firebase I'm getting on the items but not the key for each item.So that's why I'm unable to edit or delete items
Kindly help me out on how to do this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kT89.png)

here is my code of add item in the firebase.

```
  export const addMeasurement = params => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(measurementLoading());
    try {
      firebaseService
        .database()
        .ref('/Measurements')
        .push(params)
        .then(res => {
          measurementAdded(res);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(measurementFailed(err));
    }
  };
};
```

Here is the code to get items from firebase which was stored early

```
 export const getMeasurements = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(measurementLoading());
    try {
      const ref = firebaseService.database().ref('/Measurements');
      ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        const values = snapshot.val();

        if (values !== null) {
          const newFreshArr = Object.values(values);

          dispatch(measurementSuccess(newFreshArr));
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(measurementFailed(err));
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of a snapshot like so:
`let path = snapshot.ref.path.toString();`.
You can then make changes to your Firebase database using that path.
Here’s the documentation on that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref